# The diffeomorphism of neighbourhood

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

$M,N$ are two smooth $n$-manifolds and $A$ is a subset of $M$. A smooth mapping $f$ from $M$ to $N$ has the property that $df$ is nonsingular and $f$ is injective on $A$. Is there a neighbourhood $U$ of $A$ such that $f$ is a diffeomorphism from $U$ to its image?

Comment: Neighbourhood _containing_ A, or neighbourhood _contained_ in A? Actually, I think the answer either way is no...

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is allowed to be arbitrary, the answer is no.  Here's a counterexample: let $M=\mathbb R$, $N=\mathbb R^2$, $A = [0,2\pi)$, and $f(t) = (\cos t,\sin t)$.  Then any smooth extension of $f$ to a neighborhood of $A$ will take a small neighborhood of $0$ onto a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, and thus cannot be injective.

If $A$ is compact, then the conjecture is true. Here's a sketch of a proof. First, let $F$ be any smooth extension of $f$ to an open neighborhood $U$ of $A$.  After shrinking $U$ if necessary, we can arrange that $dF_x$ is nonsingular for all $x\in U$, so $F$ is a local diffeomorphism.  Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $N$, and give $U$ the pullback metric $F^*g$, so $F$ is a local isometry.

For each $x\in A$, choose $\epsilon_x>0$ small enough that $F$ is injective on $B_{3\epsilon}(x)$, and such that the distance from $F(x)$ to the compact set $F(A)\smallsetminus B_{2\epsilon_x}(F(x))$ is greater than $\epsilon_x$.   Then the restriction of $F$ to the open set $\bigcup_{x\in A} B_{\epsilon_x}(x)$ is an injective local diffeomorphism, hence a diffeomorphism.

Comment: I was thinking of a similar proof. I am writing it here in case anyone is interested: by contradiction suppose that $F$ is not inyecive on the sets $B(A,1/n) := \{x \in M: d(x,A)<1/n\}$. Hence there are two sequences, $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that: $a_n,b_n \in B(A,1/n)$, $a_n \neq b_n$ but $F(a_n) = F(b_n)$. Since $A$ is compact, there is a compact set $K \supset B(A,1/n)$ for n big enough. For that reason I can suppose that $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$. Since $F$ is locally inyective it follows that $a\neq b$ and since $A$ is compact $a,b \in A$. But $F(a)=F(b)$, absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M:={\mathbb R}$ and $N:={\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$ and consider the quotient map $f:\ t\mapsto [t]$. Then $df={\rm id}$ $\ (t\in{\mathbb R})$, and $f$ is injective on $A:=[0,1[\ $, but there is no neighborhood $U$ of $A$ such that $f$ can be extended to a diffeomorphism $\tilde f:\ U\to N$.